# Visual Studio 2010 opens wrong file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio has a habit of opening the wrong file in my solution - only a small proportion of the time, but several times a day and often enough to be annoying.  It can happen when doing any of the following:

- Opening a file from solution explorer
- Using F7 to switch between aspx and code behind
- Right clicking a method and selecting "go to declaration"

Has anyone else experienced this and have any ideas as to what could cause / fix this?

**Update:** I've finally got round to installing SP1 and it still occurs so I'm back to looking for a solution.

In case it's relevant, I've got both Resharper 5.1 and Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools installed.

**Update 2:** It looks like Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools was part of the problem, I’ve uninstalled it and have not had issues since.

Comment: I get this behaviour: double click on a .cs class file in Solution Explorer; the file opens but the focus is switched to an already open  HTML/XML file instead (.cshtml, .config, ...). I then have to manually locate the file I double-clicked. As one of the answers says, this could be to do with Power Tools tab display but I don't want to uninstall Power Tools.

Comment: @RobKent uninstalling Power Tools fixed this for me, but as they're rather useful I agree it's not an ideal solution!

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem in VS 2017. Unfortunately the option names have been changed. Did anybody fix this error in VS 2017?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I uninstalled Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you service pack 1 installed?

Comment: No I haven't - Thanks for the suggestion - I'll try installing it.

Comment: I've installed SP1 and it still happens frequently.

Comment: I've installed SP1 and it still happens. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ozzie Perez - do you have Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools installed? uninstalling it seems to have solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Andy - Yeah, it's something with certain feature(s) of VS Productivity Power Tools. It's been totally stable after I disabled features I don't use by going to Tools>Options>Productivity Power Tools. Here are the ones I disabled: Tab Wells, Fixed Mixed Tabs, Column Guides, Colorized Parameter Help, Html Copy, Middle-click Scrolling, Solution Navigator, Organize VB Imports, and Quick Access.

Comment: @Ozzie Perez - Thanks - I'll try doing the same myself.